# Multiple AJAX XML requests with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, recursive-query

I'm trying to create an XML parser in Javascript with jQuery and receives an xml file with some information plus any number of links to other XML files. When the parser runs, it can find, for example, 3 tags with links to other XML files. These will begin being processed and printed, one by one until all links are posted on the page. This means that the underlying XML files will be printed out recursively while parsing the first xml-file. All xml files have the same structure and the underlying may also have links, just like the first xml file.

Is it possible that in this way, recursive retrive and process of XML files that are linked to each other, and if so how?

Comment: My question is no ordinary question...

Comment: jQuery have an excellence xml parser, just do `$('your xml')` and done. Why need to rewrite?

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu you have to be careful with $('your xml'), because sometimes it doesn't work in IE (requires $(document.createElement('root and other tags'))-ing), because jQuery doesn't automatically register the element with the dom and IE thinks the tag isn't closed.

Comment: Though I'm by no means saying that you should (or would) test for IE :)

Comment: I will notice that, thank you

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want <sometag src='xml2.xml'> and contents of the xml2.xml file inserted inside <sometag> ?

Comment: The problem lies in that when i parse one file with links to other xml files, it will not work. I cant work with several xml-files simultanusly. When start parsing the first xml file, i will not be finished with it before start processing next, and so on.

Comment: Luka Ramishvili: thats allmost right. I want to make it possible to show all the xml-files content like a tree and with infinite depth.

Comment: I suggest you do more research, because just sitting down and trying to write the code would yield in working code. If you lack the knowledge about jquery and xml, then search for tutorials covering underlying concepts. I will really help, I guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cross browser xml parsing library like [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/) to handle setting up the DOM Parser for each browser. Then when you find a node with another XML link you can just call your function which should do the following:

1. Retrieve XML Document
2. Set up DOM Parser
3. Parse the file
4. If a link is found call this function again (recursion)
5. If EOF stop (stopping condition)